# Azure: Get resource for azure automation

Tags: azure, automation

I have runbook in Azure that i want to use in different RG,

My code

```
 $vms = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName RG-TEST
foreach($vm in $vms)
{
   $statuscheck = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName RG-TEST -Name $vm.Name -Status 
    if($statuscheck.Statuses.DisplayStatus[1] -eq "VM running")
    {  

        Write-Output "Stopping virtual machine...$($vm.Name)"

        Stop-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name -Force
    }   
    else
    {
        Write-output "Virtual machine $($vm.Name) is already in stopped state"
    }
}
```

How can I update the code that the script will get the name of the RG where it's located,

So that the RG is not hard coded

Dont know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this

```
$rgs = $(Get-AzVM)
# Get Distinct RG Names
$rgs = $rgs | Select-Object -Property ResourceGroupName | Sort-Object -Unique
foreach($rg in $rgs){
  $vms = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName
    foreach($vm in $vms)
    {
    $statuscheck = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name -Status 
        if($statuscheck.Statuses.DisplayStatus[1] -eq "VM running")
        {  

            Write-Output "Stopping virtual machine...$($vm.Name)"

            Stop-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName  -Name $vm.Name -Force
        }   
        else
        {
            Write-output "Virtual machine $($vm.Name) is already in stopped state"
        }
    }
}
```